# Why does Laravel Sanctum append token key to the plainTextToken?

Tags: laravel, hash, laravel-sanctum, sanctum

Referring to the following code from Sanctum:

```
public function createToken(string $name, array $abilities = ['*'])
    {
        $token = $this->tokens()->create([
            'name' => $name,
            'token' => hash('sha256', $plainTextToken = Str::random(40)),
            'abilities' => $abilities,
        ]);

        return new NewAccessToken($token, $token->getKey().'|'.$plainTextToken);
    }
```

Source: https://github.com/laravel/sanctum/blob/31fbe6f85aee080c4dc2f9b03dc6dd5d0ee72473/src/HasApiTokens.php#L44-L53

Why does Sanctum append `$token->getKey()` to the `$plainTextToken`? In other words, what is the purpose of the `$token->getKey()` part? Is it used during authentication as a key to retrieve the encrypted token string and compare it using `Hash::check` or something?

I have another question: The migration that creates the personal_access_tokens table indicates that the token column is unique. However, in the above code I can see that the value stored in the token column is just a hashed value of a random string `hash('sha256', $plainTextToken = Str::random(40))`. Does the hash function always return unique values so that it doesn't violate the unique constraint?

My first thought was that the `$token->getKey()` should be appended to the encrypted string to make it unique. But I think this is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

Sanctum **createToken function**  creates a string of 40 characters,

```
Str::random(40)
```

then hashs it but before hashing, stores it into a variable **$plainTextToken**.

```
hash('sha256', $plainTextToken = Str::random(40))
```

Hashed token goes to the database and un-hashed token returns to user.

```
 $token = $this->tokens()->create([
        'name' => $name,
        'token' => hash('sha256', $plainTextToken = Str::random(40)),
        'abilities' => $abilities,
    ]);
```

Return the un-hashed part to the user with primary key of database record.
the primary key helps to find the token quickly. if you remove primary key it will work too.

```
 return new NewAccessToken($token, $token->getKey().'|'.$plainTextToken)
```